# How to handle Null Pointer Exception in this block of code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, try-catch

We have the following snippet of code in Spring-Boot:

```
@Value("${service.image.cloud.host}")
String imgUrl;

private final ImageValidationProperties imageValidationProperties;

public ImageResponse getImageslistFromCloud(String image, Integer cloud) {
    String imageNumber = "0RC";
    String url = imgUrl;
    if (cloud != null) {
        imageNumber = imageValidationProperties.getImagesFromCloud(cloud);
        url = imageValidationProperties.getUrlFromCloud(cloud);
    }
    log.debug("Request images", imageNumber);
    ResponseEntity<ImageResponse> imgResponse = null;
    try {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        imgResponse = template.getForEntity(url.concat(imageNumber).concat(imgUrl), ImageResponse.class);
        return imgResponse.getBody();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error: {}", e);
        return imgResponse.getBody();
    }

}
```

My supervisor told me that it could throw a `Null Pointer Exception` which is not handled, but I dont understand how it could be fixed. I have used `try` and `catch` already so I am not sure what could go wrong.
Someone has idea what could be wrong? I apperciate any help :)

Comment: The last return of your method `return imgResponse.getBody()` (in the catch block) assumes that `imgResponse` is not null, even though the block of code setting it up has thrown an exception.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `RestTemplate.getForEntity` always returns not-null?

Comment: @khelwood thanks for your answer! if I dont include a return statement it complains, that I should change method signature to void. What should I do in this case?

Comment: It's up to you. What should your method do when it cannot return the thing it is supposed to? Maybe it should throw an exception that indicates the problem. Maybe it should return null. It's up to you how your method is designed and how the code that calls your method expects it to deal with failure.

Answer (score 1):

@Value property is null because your Class doesn't have a Bean, try to annotate your class with @Service, @Component or even use a @Bean annotation.

Comment: that doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: service.image.cloud.host can be defined but if the class doesn't have the correct annotation will receive a null value

Answer (score 1):

Your catch block will throw a NullPointerException if template.getForEntity resulted in an HTTP error (e.g. if the resource could not be found). In this case imgResponse is still null and you call the getBody() method on it. Instead you should return null or use Optional as return type and return Optional.empty().

You should also avoid to catch the very common Exception and be more specific about the exceptions you want to catch.

Answer (score 0):

In try `block` you instantiated `imgResponse` field.But, In `catch` block you directly returned response by using `imgResponse.getBody();` statement. Which will possibly throw `NullPointerException`.

One best way to avoid `NullPointerException` is to use [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Which could potential save to break your code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with imgResponse.getBody() in the catch block. imgResponse is still null in the catch block, which will throw NPE when imgResponse.getBody() is called.

Another place is: you need to initialize the variable imageValidationProperties as well, otherwise its method call will result in null pointer exception
(imageNumber = imageValidationProperties.getImagesFromCloud(cloud);
url = imageValidationProperties.getUrlFromCloud(cloud);)